# How to move rats in a maze in Python

Tags: python, list, move, message, maze

I am really new to Python and I am trying to do a game where rats in a maze try and eat Brussel sprouts - so I have 2 rats - 'J' and 'P' and 2 classes - Rat and Maze. So far all of the functions for Rat class work - and I am stuck on the last one for the Maze class! Both the classes are intertwined.  I am having problems fixing the move method for the Maze class - here are the two classes below.

```
# The visual representation of a wall.
WALL = '#'

# The visual representation of a hallway.
HALL = '.'

# The visual representation of a brussels sprout.
SPROUT = '@'

# Constants for the directions. Use these to make Rats move.

# The left direction.
LEFT = -1

# The right direction.
RIGHT = 1

# No change in direction.
NO_CHANGE = 0

# The up direction.
UP = -1

# The down direction.
DOWN = 1

# The letters for rat_1 and rat_2 in the maze.
RAT_1_CHAR = 'J'
RAT_2_CHAR = 'P'
num_sprouts_eaten = 0



class Rat:
    """ A rat caught in a maze. """

    # Write your Rat methods here.
    def __init__(Rat, symbol, row, col):
        Rat.symbol = symbol
        Rat.row = row
        Rat.col = col

        num_sprouts_eaten = 0

    def set_location(Rat, row, col):

        Rat.row = row
        Rat.col = col

    def eat_sprout(Rat):
        num_sprouts_eaten += 1        

    def __str__(Rat):
        """ (Contact) -> str

        Return a string representation of this contact.
        """
        result = ''

        result = result + '{0} '.format(Rat.symbol) + 'at '

        result = result + '('+ '{0}'.format(Rat.row) + ', '
        result = result + '{0}'.format(Rat.col) + ') ate '
        result = result + str(num_sprouts_eaten) + ' sprouts.'
        return result
```

class Maze:
        """ A 2D maze. """

```
    def __init__(Maze, content, rat_1, rat_2):
        Maze.content= content

        Maze.rat_1 = RAT_1_CHAR
        Maze.rat_2 = RAT_2_CHAR

    def is_wall(Maze, row,col):

        return (Maze.content[row][col] == '#') 

    def get_character(Maze,row, col):
        chars = ''
        if 'J' in Maze.content[row][col]:
            chars = 'J'
        elif 'P' in Maze.content[row][col]:
            chars = 'P'
        elif '#' in Maze.content[row][col]:
            chars = WALL
        else:
            chars = HALL
        return chars

    def move(Maze, Rat, hor, ver):
        num_sprouts_left = sum(x.count('@') for x in Maze.content[row][col])
        nowalls = False
        if Rat in Maze.content[row][col] and Maze.is_wall(row, col) == True:
            NO_CHANGE = Rat.set_location(row+0,col+0)

        if Rat in Maze.content[row][col] and Maze.is_wall(row, col) == False:
            UP = Rat.set_location(row,col+1)
            if UP == SPROUT:
               Rat.eat_sprout(Rat)
               num_sprouts_left -= 1
               SPROUT=HALL
        if Rat in Maze.content[row][col] and Maze.is_wall(row, col) == False:
            DOWN = Rat.set_location(row,col-1)
            if DOWN == SPROUT:
               Rat.eat_sprout(Rat)
               num_sprouts_left -= 1
               SPROUT=HALL
        if Rat in Maze.content[row][col] and Maze.is_wall(row, col) == False:
            LEFT = Rat.set_location(row-1,col)
            if LEFT == SPROUT:
               Rat.eat_sprout(Rat)
               num_sprouts_left -= 1
               SPROUT=HALL
        if Rat in Maze.content[row][col] and Maze.is_wall(row, col) == False:
            RIGHT = Rat.set_location(row+1,col)
            if RIGHT == SPROUT:
               Rat.eat_sprout(Rat)
               num_sprouts_left -= 1
               SPROUT=HALL 

            nowalls = True

        return nowalls
```

so when I call the move method through a Maze object - I get an error message!

```
>>> d = Maze([['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], 
      ['#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#'], 
      ['#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#'], 
      ['#', '.', '.', '@', '#', '.', '#'], 
      ['#', '@', '#', '.', '@', '.', '#'], 
      ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']], 
      Rat('J', 1, 1),
      Rat('P', 1, 4))
>>> d.move('J',2,2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#167>", line 1, in <module>
    d.move('J',2,2)
  File "C:\Users\gijoe\Downloads\a2.py", line 96, in move
    num_sprouts_left = sum(x.count('@') for x in Maze.content[row][col])
NameError: global name 'row' is not defined
>>>
```

Please help me fix the error messages and move the rat to any point in the maze (as long as it is in the hall way)!

Comment: The first argument to your `Maze` and `Rat` methods should be `self`, and not `Maze` or `Rat`. Although `Maze`, `Rat` and `self` are just variables, they are conceptually different. `self` is usually used to refer to the _instance_ of the class inside of a method. Setting the first argument name to the same as the class name can also cause you problems if you wish to refer to the class, not the instance inside of a method as well.

Comment: Right off the bat, it appears row and col are not defined in your move method.  Did you mean to use row and col as parameters (instead of hor and ver)?

Comment: but ALL the other methods work Joel, so why won't this one work? the move method should work as well!!!

Comment: yes i did piccy...u are right - they are supposed to be parameters

Comment: do i need row and col or not? or how should i define them? aren't they arbitary?

Comment: I'm guessing you simply meant to use row & col instead of hor & ver, so just replace hor with col and ver with row.  Also, since num_sprouts_left is a class variable, you will want to refer to it as self.num_sprouts_left.  You'll also need to do as Joel indicated to make the first parameter of all class methods be 'self' instead of 'Maze' or 'Rat'.

Comment: You can pick any name you want for the parameters, yes. But the names of the parameters in the method signature (hor & ver in your example) need to match the names of the variables you use in the method. You can't use variables that haven't been defined within the current scope.

Comment: ok i still got the same problems  when i changed row and col instead of hor and ver 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#170>", line 1, in <module>
    d.move('J',2,2)
  File "C:\Users\gijoe\Downloads\a2.py", line 96, in move
    num_sprouts_left = sum(x.count('@') for x in Maze.content[row][col])
NameError: global name 'row' is not defined

Comment: and so now why am I getting all false solutions? cause the boolean is supposed to return true but i get false!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you do `Maze.content[row][col]`, python looks for variables named `row` and `col` and tries to use them as indices for `Maze.content`. Since `row` (and `col`) are not defined in `move()`, and since they are also not defined globally, python throws a `NameError`.

There is a further problem though. Even *if* you set `row = someNumber` and `col = someOtherNumber` prior to that line, you still not get your expected result.
Calling `Maze.content[row][col]` will return a string of length one. (with values "#", "@", or "_"). So doing x.count("@") on that string will either return a 1 or 0. And since you're operating on a string of length 1, `num_sprouts_left` will only take values 1 or 0.

I assume that you wish to iterate through the *entire* maze to count the number of sprouts. You would do that like this:

```
num_sprouts_left = sum(row.count('@') for row in Maze.content)
```

In the above case, `row` *is* being assigned a value in the generator expression. (In fact it's being assigned multiple values, a different one for each iteration)

#### A note about using `Maze` or `Rat` as your `self` parameter:

Firstly, it really doesn't matter what you call your first parameter. You could just as easily do:

```
def set_location(balloons, row, col):

    balloons.row = row
    balloons.col = col
```

This is because python passes the *class instance* as the first parameter. The name you type there is just a variable name so that you can refer to it *inside that particular method*.

*However*

That parameter is called `self` by convention. You should call it `self` so as to keep your code clear.

*Well, why not call it `Maze` or `Rat`, like I've been doing?*
First, because it's confusing. You are not actually referring to the *class* `Maze` or `Rat` inside of any of your methods, python assigns those names the *class instance*. Someone (yourself included) might read your code later and think that you are referring to the class and not the instance.

Second, because it overwrites the class name within that method. What if you actually wanted to refer to the class within that method? You can't, because you overwrote that name with your poorly named parameter.

Comment: ok but i'm still getting all Falses now ...so how can i get it to return True sometimes?

Comment: Are you talking about `nowalls`? Most likely, one of your other methods is not working correctly. Have you _thoroughly tested_ all of your other methods to ensure that they behave appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your program.  I'll point out some of the major ones, and let you work on them.  As you learn Python, keep in mind that the Python documentaion on python.org is your friend.

- You need to declare Rat objects for each rat.  You might do this as follows:

  `JRat = Rat('J', 1, 1)`

  `PRat = Rat('P', 1, 4)`

Then, to move the 'J' rat, you would say, `d.Move(JRat, 2, 2)`

- As Joel noted, the first parameter of each class method should be self.  It's a Python convention, and you might as well learn it the way everyone else does it.  So, for example, your move method would be defined as follows:

  `def move(self, Rat, hor, ver):`

Then, in the move method, to refer to a class variable, such as content, you would use `self.content`.

You should also not use a class name as a parameter to a function.  While this is legal in Python, it's a somewhat advanced technique, and I'm guessing this is not what you intend.  So, the move method would be better defined as:

```
def move(self, rat, hor, ver):
```

Then you would use `rat` (lower-case r) instead of `Rat` in your move method to refer to the rat parameter.

- Don't reassign constants in your move method.  You have various constants defined, like WALL, HALL, SPROUT, LEFT, RIGHT, etc.  If you intend for these to be used as global constants (which I think you do), you would never use these on the left side of an assignment statement.  So, for example, the statement

  `UP = Rat.set_location(row,col+1)`

doesn't do what you expect.

- It would be a good idea to add some comments for each function to indicate what it is doing, and what each parameter does.  This will force you to think through what it is you want to accomplish.  So, when documenting the move method, ask yourself what the 'hor' and 'ver' parameters are used for.  Do they indicate the amount of
  distance the rat will be moving?  Or, do they indicate the absolute coordinate that the rat will be moving to?

I'll stop here and let you do some more investigation.  I know it's a pain, but we often learn the best through struggling.

Good luck.

Comment: im still stuck guys...how do i get the rat to move up down left and right?

Comment: @BenStein: That is a separate topic. You should post a separate question for that.